# GUI.BeginScrollView not working

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I made a GUI Tool for Unity
I tryed to add ScrollView like this before the for loop that creates GameObject buttons :

```
scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(Screen.width-1,20,0,Screen.height-60),scrollPosition,new Rect(0,0,Screen.width-20, Screen.height-80),false,false,GUIStyle.none,GUI.skin.verticalScrollbar);
```

and I use GUI.EndScrollView after the for loop that creates Buttons

Comment: The code you have linked does not include a call to BeginScrollView. What are the observable symptoms when you add these calls?

Comment: Now It's In the Link. also, all i noticed is that a Rect has been created on top of my buttons.

Comment: i verified those buttons are saved and instanciated as they should
only scrollview creates some sort of layer on top of them
if I add Buttons they're added but everything hidden in the back.
Also, the scrollHandler doesn't become tinier if i add a bunch of buttons
that means that they're not included in scrollalble area

Comment: I notice you deleted your question. If you've solved your issue, would you like to instead post your solution as an Answer that can help future developers struggling with scroll views?

Comment: it was just a stupid mistake i made, i believe. i only replaced ```Screen.width-1``` with 0 and it was solved. i did not reade the description well.
 i think no one would make such a mistake. That's why i deleted it. You think i should keep it?

Comment: I see the same mistakes made repeatedly, so I think it's worthwhile. Try editing your question and and an answer to make the thread you *wish* you had found when first searching for help on this issue. It might help the next person in your shoes. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread the definition of ScrollView.
The first Rect defines the Rectangle on the screen to use for the ScrollView. and the Second is the rectangle used inside the scrollview. that means that i should not position ScreenWidth-1 which makes it hidden from me

In other words, i should replace `Screen.width-1` with `0`